# Telerik radGridView add childrow

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

i have a telerik grid in my winform application in which i have parent & child templates. I have added data manually from database.

i have added child templates like following

```
radGrid.MasterTemplate.Templates.Add(gridViewTemplate);
```

Now i want to manually add childrow of 3rd parent row.
I have tried following codes to add child row, but i have failed.

```
radfileentry.Templates[0].Rows.AddNew();
radfileentry.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].Rows.AddNew();
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research i come to know that we can't directly add child row, so i have first saved the data to database and then refreshed my `Master` and `Child` templates, and it works!

To refresh i have used the following statements

```
radGridView.MasterTemplate.Refresh();
radGridView.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].Refresh();
```